# How do I give my .ASHX access to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, ashx, configurationmanager

I have included the same files that other pages have that use it but for some reason it's just not finding it. How do I include access to it?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Can you show some code? And what test did you perform that led you to think the .ashx was not finding it? It should just work.

Comment: I had to include System.Configuration I believe

Answer (score 3):

As you stated in your comment you need to ensure the project that has the handler has a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly. You also could add a `using` directive to make the namespace a little easier to use.

With using directive (`using System.Configuration`)

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"]
```